# what exactly is vim's advance

Tags: vim, ide

I've not used VIM as an editor before, but I'm curious about it and about why people use command-line tools like VIM and GDB. I'm curious to know whether people think it's better than tools like Visual Studio.

Could people who do use it share it's best features? This might increase my motivation to learn it. The first IDE I ever used as a kid was Visual Basic. I'm curious to know whether people who use VIM now used it when they first stared using computers?

Comment: @bhinesley: it looks to me like the editor tried very hard to prevent this question from being shot down by removing argumentative/subjective elements and adding concrete question formulations. @ shengy no I learnt vim only after I started my professional work, and before ever even seeing Linux. These days I admit I use Linux primarily,  despite being raised on Windows, with Borland an Microsoft IDEs (oh, and my work still involves Microsoft, mostly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Deleted the "vi is not an IDE" - don't want to start an editor war)

You will find a vi clone on virtually every Unix/Linux system out there - so being comfortable with using vi is a useful skill - the Mac includes a vi clone too.

Its not so useful on Windows as its not there by default - but Notepad whilst awful is a passable editor in an emergency.  I wouldn't install vim on Windows to have a decent editor, I would either use Visual Studio if installed or install Notepad++

And yes, vi was the first editor I learned to use - but I would normally use a decent IDE, but knowing basic vi commands is useful.

Comment: Remember, `vim` != `vi` (`vim > vi`)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - do understand that.  I still think that its worth having some basic vi knowledge, even if you don't abandon your other IDEs to use vim.  I just wondered whether OP understood that vim is part of a larger family of related editors.

Answer (score 2):

Many people use vim as an IDE. There are a large set of scripts to add IDE like functionality, and you can create your own scripts too.

People also really like the way you can minimize keystrokes and avoid the mouse. So much, in fact, that things like http://vimgolf.com/ exist to see how few keystrokes you can use to do some sort of edit.

Comment: I prefer Vim for my IDE work (even using ViEmu in Visual Studio, ViMode in Monodevelop). For advanced editing tasks i'll still fireup gvim. However I almost completely disagree on the usefulness of vimgolf: it leads to solutions that are marginally shorter but exponentially more contrived, harder to remember and more errorprone.  Like everywhere in Software development you should prefer to use the _correct algorithm_ but refrain from (premature) optimizations. On vimgolf, look to the simplest of the shorter answers

Answer (score 2):

Vim is terse, concise, and optimized for people with only two hands.